# Equivalent to GNU find -printf flag in other find implementations

Tags: find, posix

Specifically, in mkinitcpio the command `find -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\0'` is used, what would be a way to recreate a command with identical output without the -printf flag. https://git.archlinux.org/mkinitcpio.git/tree/mkinitcpio This is the full script in case it is useful.

Comment: Do any of your file or directory names contain the newline character?

Comment: @meuh I don't know what files or directories it's finding, it's using it to find all the files to put into the initramfs.  I don't see a reason the files or directories would have a newline character though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%P` will give the relative path of the file starting from the directory used as starting point, so that if `find` is run with `some/path` as starting point and it finds the pathname `some/path/to/file`, then `%P` will expand to `to/file`.

When GNU `find` is not given a starting point (as in the command given in the question), it will use the current directory (`.`) as the starting point.  The `%P` format will therefore remove `./` from the found paths in this case.

To do the same thing as `-printf '%P\0'` with a non-GNU `find` implementations, assuming `-mindepth` is still available (as in `find` on BSD systems):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "%s\0" "${pathname#./}"
    done' sh {} +
```

The embedded `sh -c` script will get a batch of pathnames from `find` to work on and uses a standard parameter expansion that removes the initial `./` from the pathname before printing it with a terminating nul-character.

---

The same thing, but with a variable holding the *single* top-level directory path:

```
topdir=/some/path

find "$topdir" -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c '
    topdir=${1%/}; shift
    for pathname do
        printf "%s\0" "${pathname#$topdir/}"
    done' sh "$topdir" {} +
```

Comment: `-mindepth 1` can be written standardly with `! -name .` or `! -path .`

Answer (score 0):

In `-printf '%P\0'` the `%P` is just removing the initial `./` from the front of the filename. You can do the equivalent with `sed 's|^\./||'`. The `\0` part produces a null character instead of newline between each filename. You can convert newline to null with `tr '\n' '\0'`.  So you can try

```
find . -mindepth 1 -print | sed 's|^\./||' | tr '\n' '\0'
```

If any names contain a newline, this will corrupt them, translating that newline to null and transform file paths such as `./foo<newline>./bar` to `foo<null>bar`.