# Do not list parent directory as part of subdirectories when using find

Tags: find

Suppose I have this going:

```bash
$ find ./src -name '*.txt'
./src/file1.txt
./src/subdir1/file2.txt
./src/subdir1/subsubdir1/file3.txt
./src/subdir2/file4.txt
```

I want to exclude the directory being searched, so something like:

`./file1.txt` instead of `./src/file1.txt`
`./subdir1/file2.txt` instead of `./src/subdir1/file2.txt` and so on.

Adding `-mindepth 1` didn't do anything.

Is it possible to do what I'm after purely in `find`?

Comment: Which `find` implementation are you using? for GNU `find`, there's `-printf '%P\n'` - see also [Equivalent to GNU find -printf flag in other find implementations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469815/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver I am indeed using GNU `find`, thanks for the `-printf` flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on what [@steeldriver said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734848/do-not-list-parent-directory-as-part-of-subdirectories-when-using-find#comment1395015_734848):

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)" # create temporary directory
direnv: unloading
$ mkdir foo bar
$ touch foo/1 bar/2
$ find foo bar -type f -name '*' -printf '%P\n'
1
2
```

The `%P` formatting string is documented as follows by the GNU `find` manual:

> `%P`
> File's name with the name of the starting-point under
> which it was found removed.

Here, "file's name" means the pathname of the found file, not just the filename.

Answer (score 9):

For situations where you don't have a version of `find` that supports `-printf '%P'` you can use this alternative structure to avoid including the search path.

Starting point as in the question:

> ```
> find ./src -name '*.txt'
> ```

Same but without the search path in the results

```
( cd ./src && find . -name '*.txt' )
```

Assuming the file structure shown in your question, the result is

```
./file1.txt
./subdir1/file2.txt
./subdir1/subsubdir1/file3.txt
./subdir2/file4.txt
```